# R shiny - shiny app works well locally and on others shiny server but it does not work on my server. It gives me NO error message

Tags: r, linux, shiny, redhat

I want to transfer a R application (working well on an actual shiny server with an OS RHEL6.8) to another "new" shiny server.
My application is running well on the first server. The idea is to put it on an other server with better performances.

My new server has the following settings :

```
OS : Redhat Enterprise Linux 7.2 with:       
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) -- "Short Summer"                                     
Shiny Server v1.5.6.875 / Node.js v6.10.3                                                        
RStudio Server 1.0.153                                                                       
MySQL v15.1 Distrib 5.5.44-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1  
Oracle OCI (Oracle Call Interface) Release 12.1.0.2.0
```

When I test my application on Rstudio locally (on the server) it's working but when I go on the URL it's not working. The grey screen appears 1/2 seconds after the loading of the URL and I obtain the generic error : “Disconnected from the server”.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you using shiny server? Have you checked the logs?

Comment: Yes I have shiny server. And the log tell me nothing. There is no error message in fact. Locally everything is working. It crash on the web only

Comment: I suggest you comment out most of the code and step through it, it might be your `MySQL` or `Oracle OCI` connection issues

Comment: Have you checked your shiny server status ? And do you manage to connect to the shiny server welcome page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot for your help ! Infact it was due to some packages "r2excel", and "openxlsx". All my packages linked to excel and java created the problem. I have removed them and all is alright !